# How to add notification bar control on React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I'm making an audio player app but I want to add the functionality of a notification bar control where you control the music like this:

[image: Example (Sorry for the huge image)]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult, I found that you can use react-native-music-control which is buggy or you can use react-native-track-player which says it works with expo but I still haven't managed to get it to work... Good luck

Comment: I tried `react-native-music-control` on managed and bare expo project but both didn't work, I will try `react-native-track-player` on bare if it works or not. But thanks.

Comment: I think you might have to eject to be able to use these libraries.